# Working with values of 0 and 1 (Boolean)

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Is

```
f = a'ab;
```

the same as

```
f = 1
```

Is this possible? I got this when I was simplifying something.

Comment: What does `'` stand for?

Comment: @AljoshaBre, the "prime" marker (either an overbar where available, or a tick following the object being inverted) normally means inversion (NOT) in Boolean algebra.

Comment: Interesting, and I was thought it's `!` that is used as a symbol for negation.

Comment: That's the C way since it's the operator for logical inversion. Boolean algebra, however, comes from the _math_ world that pre-dates even C :-) And, in fact, the prime notation is used in other places such as matrices where `a` multiplied by `a'` gives the unit matrix.

Comment: @paxdiablo Hahah, I meant `¬` :) Considering matrices, yup, that's how I was taught too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's meant to represent (and I think this is the likely case):

```
NOT-a AND a AND b
```

then, no, it's false no matter the values of `a` or `b`. That's because one of `a` or `NOT-a` is definitely false, `FALSE AND anything` is false and the operation is associative: `(a AND b) AND c == a AND (b AND c)`.

If it's meant to represent:

```
NOT-a OR a OR b
```

then, yes, it's true no matter the values of `a` or `b`. That's because one of `a` or `NOT-a` is definitely true and `TRUE OR anything` is true. The associativity rules also apply here.